# how to get class name from ui.item or event from function(event,ui)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I want to get the class name from a function which has 2 parameters, `event` and `ui`.

Example:

`$(document).tooltip({
    show: null,
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom"
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        alert(event.target) 
        ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + 10 }, "fast" );
    }
});`

How to get the class name from the given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `event` object has a `target` attribute (The DOM element that initiated the event).

Hence:

```
$(event.target) //gives you a jQuery wrapper on the DOM element that initiated the event
```

In order to get its class, you can do the following:

```
 $(event.target).attr("class")
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I hope this answers your question.

Regarding "ui.item" that you've mentioned - you can do pretty much the same with it too:

```
$(ui.item).attr("class")
```

From the few hints you gave me after my questions, I'm guessing you're trying to change the appearance of the tooltip widget, and that's why you're trying to get the "class".

Take a look at jQuery UI Tooltip widget documentation

```
ui-tooltip: The outer container for the tooltip.
ui-tooltip-content: The content of the tooltip.
```

**EDIT:**

If none of these were what you looked for, you can always investigate the `event` object.
take a look at:

```
event.currentTarget
event.delegateTarget
event.relatedTarget
event.data
event.toElement
```

Comment: Sorry to tell that both of these method are not working, i have gotten undefined value. lets say i have <span class='tooltip_class' title='show tooltip'>blah</span> but all i got is undefined.

Comment: So the event is fired on the <html> tag, what does alert(ui.item) say?

Comment: i got undefined value.

Comment: OK. Which event are you handling? close, create, or open?

Comment: open which under tooltip event.

Comment: I saw your update on the question, the class of which object are you trying to get?

Comment: lets say i have <span class='tooltip_class' title='show title'>Sample</span>. And i want to show the span class

Comment: The span is the tooltip itself? or another unrelated object?

Comment: Well, the jquery tooltip function will verify any element has title and create a tooltip for them.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but, if it's not what you're looking for, I'd suggest you to try also: alert(event.currentTarget), or alert(event.data) or alert(event.relatedTarget). The one of them that gives you the "element" you look for, you can do .attr("class") on it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am testing it out now.

Comment: Thanks for your time!! event.toElement has gotten me the class attribute for me!!